# Query Regarding Google MAP API Key

Tags: google-maps

We are using Gmap API Key in our application.

We have  web based mobile application for delivery of medication at pharmacy store. In this application we use Gmap, to display direction/path between pharmacy store.

1. It show Sample Period 28 Days, does it mean we have to generate another API Key after 28 days. If "Yes" then can you please guide us to get solution regarding it.
2. API Key which I have generated if for "Allow All Referrer", do u restrict the use of API Key at domain name level.
3. How many direction request can be generated in Courtesy limit and what if its exceeded..
4. Can we generate new API Key, after previous API Key is expired.

Comment: have you tried to contact google with your query? as they look very specific to their policy usage.

Comment: Questions on Google Maps which don't relate to actual programming issues should be asked in the Google Group at http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3.

Comment: since you need an api key, you are probably using version 2 of the api. keep in mind that this is deprecated. you should consider using the newer version3, which doesn't require an api key.

Comment: @aniri: Some Version 3 libraries do require a key; Version 3 maps *can* have a key, which gives access to statistics reporting and uprated limits (via billing).

Answer (score 0):

Check the terms of Usage for Google Maps
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

Query 1) It show Sample Period 28 Days, does it mean we have to generate another API Key after 28 days. If "Yes" then can you please guide us to get solution regarding it.**strong text**

I dont think you have to Generate another key after 28 days
I have used same key for a much longer time period

Query 3) How many direction request can be generated in Courtesy limit and what if its exceeded..

Check the official documentation link.

Query 4) Can we generate new API Key, after previous API Key is expired.

Yes

Answer (score 0):

Query:1) It show Sample Period 28 Days, does it mean we have to generate another API Key after 28 days. If "Yes" then can you please guide us to get solution regarding it.

Ans..> API key never Expired,It will remain valid as long as you not delete the key or the project associated with the key.

Query:2) API Key which I have generated if for "Allow All Referrer", do u restrict the use of API Key at domain name level.

Ans..> When we create a Google Maps API key, it can be locked to only be used on specific domains that you authorize. These domain names are called "referrers", and your API key won't work on other domains

Query:3) How many direction request can be generated in Courtesy limit and what if its exceeded..

Ans..> 2,500 directions requests per 24 hour period.

Query:4) Can we generate new API Key, after previous API Key is expired.

Ans..> Yes we can generate New API Key if previous key is expired