# GMAP API v2 Key expires

Tags: google-maps

I have generated GMAP API v2 Key. 
In reports section below api access in console window, it show key expires in 28 days.
Does this key expires

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query Regarding Google MAP API Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893591/query-regarding-google-map-api-key)

Comment: hi ,well the key does not expire. but api v2 is a deprecated version. why dont you use version 3.